# Zend Framework 2 Form Collection Element via annotations on Doctrine Entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a Zend Framework 2 project with Doctrine installed/configured. I am using the Zend Form annotations directly on entities to generate forms to display/edit entity data. I am running into a problem:

An entity (Vendor) with a collection of sub-entities (Territory) configured in a ManyToMany relationship. The doctrine relationship works fine, however the zend form annotations I have added

```
/*
 * ...doctrine annotations...
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Collection")
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Territory", "target_element": {"type": "\DocurepVendor\Form\TerritoryFieldset"}})
 */
```

Create the fieldset object I've made, but do not name the field names as an array. (inputs are all named city instead of city[]) so when I submit the update form, the mapper expects an array but only finds a string and fails.

Here is my fieldset code.

**TerritoryFieldset.php**

```
namespace DocurepVendor\Form;

use \Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class TerritoryFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array()) {
        parent::__construct('Locations', $options);
        $this->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods())
                ->setObject(new \DocurepLocation\Entity\Territory());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'city',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'City'
            ),
            'attributes' => array()
        ))->add(array(
            'name' => 'state',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'State'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => 'required'
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array();
    }

}
```

If I set the name in the fieldset to 'city[]' instead of 'city', the fieldset doesn't even populate with the doctrine data.

I'm not sure whether this is something I need to configure in the sub-element field set, the parent element's annotations, somewhere else entirely, or if this simply cannot be done and I need to implement this in another way. Can somebody give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the Doctrine Hydrator instead of \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods()

```
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

..

$this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator())
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and see if this handles collections as I would like. Thanks.

Comment: @Fousheezy could you make it work? I'm having a hard time using collections and annotations…